# How can I update a graphql entry?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a schema as follows:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  locations: [Location]
}

type Location @model {
  id: ID!
  listOfPictures: [String]
  address: String!
  owner: User
}
```

Currently I have entries to both Locations and Users.  The entries for my Locations are all null.
I want to update one of my Locations, of ID '1234' to have the field 'owner' set to the User of ID '5678'.

What is the correct syntax for this?  What do I have to enter into he Appsync console?

Additionally, how could I update the 'locations' field of my User of id 'abc' model to add a Location, to the array of Locations, of Location with id 'def' ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your data by using mutations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/quickstart-write-queries.html